AWS AppSync subscription with ApolloClient in React: 2024
Is anyone still able to work with AppSync, and ApolloClient in React in 2024?
I see a lot of discussions, sadly all the solutions are suggesting a different approach. And despite me following the documentation, I'm not able to establish a connection for subscription on AppSync from the ApolloClient:
This is what my ApolloClient looks like:
import {ApolloLink, ApolloProvider, createHttpLink} from "@apollo/client";
import {InMemoryCache} from "@apollo/client/cache";
import {ApolloClient} from "@apollo/client/core";
import {createSubscriptionHandshakeLink} from "aws-appsync-subscription-link";

const subscriptionLink = () => {
  const url = process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URL;
  const region = "eu-east-1";
  let jwtToken;

  getToken().then((value) => { //This is an internal async method
    jwtToken = value;
  });

  const auth = {
    type: "OPENID_CONNECT",
    jwtToken,
  };

  console.log("creating subscription link");

  return createSubscriptionHandshakeLink({url, region, auth}, httpLink);
};

const link = ApolloLink.from([subscriptionLink]);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
link, 
cache: new InMemoryCache({...})
});

export const Apollo = ({children}) => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>
);

This is how I'm trying to test the subscription:
  const SUBS_QUERY= gql`
  subscription onExampleMutation(
    $event: exampleMutationRequest!
  ) {
    onExampleMutation(event: $event) {
      message
      status
      statusCode
    }
  }
`;

  const {data: subscriptionData, loading: subscriptionLoader} = useSubscription(
    SUBS_QUERY,
    {variables: {event: {...DEFAULT}}},
  );

  const subscriptionData= subscriptionLoader
    ? []
    : subscriptionData;

  console.log(
    "Output from subscription: ",
    subscriptionData,
  );

Error that I'm getting: Message: Subscriptions over MQTT is not supported.
I've most of the things mentioned in this solution with a similar title:
AppSync subscriptions with ApolloClient in React
Except using the "aws-appsync" client, the docs in "aws-appsync-subscription-link" don't mention that requirement, so I'm not sure if that is even required.

Have you tried calling your subscriptionLink function: const link = ApolloLink.from([subscriptionLink()]);?

Inspired by an issue in the "aws-appsync-subscription-link" repo (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/628)
Have you tried the syntax they suggest, skipping the second argument to createSubscriptionHandshakeLink?
createSubscriptionHandshakeLink({ url, region, auth })


Hey thanks for responding. Removing httpLink didn't change anything.
